# Is $ \ \bar{Z} \ $ a polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $ \ \bar{Z} \ $ a polynomial ?

On the assumption that $z$ is a complex variable.

This is somehow a silly question but confuses me.
I think $\bar z$ is a polynomial in $\bar z$ not in $z$.

Do this question has other answers?

Thanks

Comment: $\bar{z}$ is a conjugate analytic polynomial (in one complex variable) hence a harmonic polynomial in two real variables (satisfies Laplace) hence a real analytic polynomial in two variables but not an analytic polynomial (the usual polynomials in one complex variable); so there are lots of classes of polynomials once we go beyond the elementary one variable ones and they have various properties

Comment: @Conrad, excellent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elementary argument as to why $\bar{z}$ is not a polynomial in $z$ is as follows: consider $\bar{z}-z$. This is $0$ infinitely often, so if $\bar{z}$ is a polynomial then $\bar{z}-z\equiv0$, the $0$ polynomial. Obviously this is not true as $\bar{z}\ne z$ for, say, $z=i$, and thus $\bar{z}$ is not a polynomial in $z$.

In $\bar{z}$, it is trivially the polynomial $f(x)\equiv x$.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not a polynomial of $z$, since $\bar{z}$ is not holomorphic (with respect to $z$), while every polynomial is. Although, yes, it is indeed a polynomial in $\bar{z}$, obviously, the monic polynomial of degree $1$ and constant term $0$.

Comment: but $z^2$ is not holomorphic though it is a polynomial, So your argument perhaps lack of logic. Kindly correct it

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR News flash: $z^2$ is holomorphic alright.

Comment: do mean holomorphic and analytic different here? because $z^2$ is not analytic. Is $1/z$ holomorphic?

Comment: $1/z^2$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ but does that mean $1/z^2$ a polynomial

Comment: In complex function theory analytic and holomorphic is the same. Square function is both. Nobody says analytic implies polynomial, but polynomial implies analytic is true. My argument is that if conjugate is polynomial, then it is analytic, but it isn't.

Comment: but $z^2$ is not analytic and hence not holomorphic.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR you are wrong

Comment: you are wrong because $z^2$ is not analytic (check it) but you said it is holomorphic in your comment

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR what is your definition of analytic?

Comment: if analytic then it must satisfy C-R equations

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR it satisfies them. Check it